# Jquery animate scroll in diagonal

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I put a diagonal scroll in my page via JQuery ?

Example, I hid the scroll bar and if my user click in some link, my page has to scroll in diagonal until some part of my page (is possible?)

this is my jquery code, but I know that just gone to the bottom of my page.

```
.animate({ scrollTop: 350}, 500);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine vertical and horizontal scrolling to make diagonal scrolling:

```
.animate({scrollTop: 350, scrollLeft: 350}, 500);
```